# moment is not a function in UAT server

Tags: angular, typescript, date, momentjs, devops

I am using angular 7 and momentjs ^2.6. I am facing an issue with momentjs in UAT server dev apps build.

I have three servers

- DEV
- QA
- UAT

I am using dev-ops management for build and deploy process. Everything is working fine in local and DEV and QA

But momentjs throwing an error in UAT server.

> Error: moment is not a function

But it is working fine if i am doing rebuild for UAT.

Does anyone have any idea for this issue? Sometimes moment is working fine but sometimes it is not working. If it is not working then if I do rebuild then its working fine in UAT.

Comment: Do you have ```build per environment``` or one build and ```relase per environment```

Comment: In your local delete node_modules and package-lock.json, than npm install, and start the application

Comment: Searching for the error message gives a lot of hits. You may check if one of them is applicable four your case.

Comment: @Drag13 I have `build for env `and just doing copy and past the  built files to IIS  on release task

Comment: @surendrakumar My problem is moment is not working in UAT server on certain time not in local. it's working in other environment without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code inside the package.json file.

Delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** from your directory.

than change the version and run NPM Install

```
 "moment-timezone": "^0.5.7",
```

TO

```
"moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
```

Comment: But why `^`  is working in Dev and QA env?, Not only UAT? Any idea?

Comment: there may be fresh installation of NPM on UAT.

Answer (score 1):

> From the key point by **@Surendra** answer, Yes!  the moment 2.5 and above version's are throwing this kind of error. After I changed to 2.5 I can able to reproduce the same error in all server.

---

> So the main problem is npm installation was happened in  4 months before in UAT, so it was installed the latest version which is moment was released 4 months before. but in QA the old version (2.4) there because the node folders are created 7 months before in QA server which means 2.4 is a latest version at that time.

***Solution:***   *So I have directly installed 2.5 in all server instead of auto update(by removed carrot symbol).*

---